# Reversing str.translate in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

If I want to remove the numbers from "He123llo Wor456ld!" with translate, I can

`from string import digits
str = "He123llo Wor456ld!"
str = str.translate(None, digits)
print str`

`>> Hello World!`

How would I reverse this to get `123456` via translate?

Comment: Whoa - why did I get voted down?  I thought this was a clear question, with work shown and done and a clear goal.

Comment: I gave a +1, but it's possible you were downvoted because you didn't really show any research effort? For example, I don't really know Python, but I did a search immediately to see if there was a corresponding `letter` object in `string`, essentially leading me to [Menno's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25515571/1454048). Although that "lack of research" by you made me learn something today, so thank you!

Comment: I was specifically looking for a reversal operation, a la greole, and used that more-specific example as just an example.  I guess I wasn't so clear, but on the Googles, I couldn't find greole's answer of how to actually reverse my operation.  It did seem obvious once I saw it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
from string import digits
s = "He123llo Wor456ld!" 
s_ = s.translate(None, digits)
s = s.translate(None, s_)
print s

>>> 123456
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for.  I was even trying to figure out the best syntax for this route.

Answer (score 1):

```
from string import letters, punctuation, whitespace
str = "He123llo Wor456ld!"
str = str.translate(None, letters + punctuation + whitespace)
print str

>> 123456
```

Still feel it's weird to 'abuse' translate like that but alas... it *does* work.

Comment: Mmmh this is searching for the inverse, instead of inverting the search result as the OP asked.

Answer (score 0):

It is a dirty way, but works!

```
your_string = "He123llo Wor456ld!"
s=""
for digit in your_string:
    try:
        int(digit)
        s+=digit
    except:
        pass

print s
```

Output:

```
>>> 123456
```